# Bootstrap check boxes lose checked state after postback. How can I stop this?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am working with an asp.net/vb.net web forms app in VS 2017 and I am using bootstrap controls.  I have several bootstrap check boxes and need to retrieve their values on a button click but also want them to retain their checked state after the button is clicked.  Currently all of the check boxes revert to the unchecked state when the button is clicked.

In addition to the code shown below I have tried adding runat="server" to each of the check boxes.  When I do this not only do they not retain their state, but I can also not retrieve the checked values.  The check boxes are within an asp update panel and I have also tried adding runat="server" to that update panel.  That also did not work.

Here is my form code:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="cbLst" value="Car">Car</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="cbLst" value="Truck">Truck</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="cbLst" value="Motorcycle">Motorcycle</label>
</div>
```

and here is my code behind the form:

```
Private Sub btnTest_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.ServerClick

Dim selected As String = Request.Form("CbLst")

TxtDiv.InnerHtml = selected

End Sub
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the checked values from the check boxes and also would like for them to retain their value.

Comment: That's how the web works, each post back is like a new page and everything is reset. If you want to make things easier, you could use the asp.net controls like [<asp:Checkbox />](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Unfortunately the asp controls don't render correctly with my page.  The bootstrap radio button control does not have this problem.  It retains its state, so there must be a way to make it work.

Comment: There isn't really a "boostrap control". It's a normal checkbox with the proper class. You can do the same with the asp control if you just set the proper class.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the .NET controls with bootstrap css.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbMotorcycle" runat="server" />Motorcycle</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but when viewed on small browsers like phones, the .net controls do not stack like the bootstrap controls and in this particular case it does not look right at all.

Comment: Hang on I might see what you are saying.  I will give it a try.  I will have to use three separate .net checkedboxlists, but it just might work.

Comment: @JamieDixson Don't use the checkedboxlists, just use regular checkbox. Could be inside a repeater. If you want to use a checkedboxlists then you'll need to manipulate its output which isn't an easy task.